# How to get %AppData% path as std::string?

Tags: c++, string, windows, path, appdata

I've read that one can use `SHGetSpecialFolderPath();` to get the AppData path. However, it returns a `TCHAR` array. I need to have an `std::string`.

How can it be converted to an `std::string`?

**Update**

I've read that it is possible to use `getenv("APPDATA")`, but that it is not available in Windows XP. I want to support Windows XP - Windows 10.

Comment: SHGetSpecialFolderPath is not supported since Windows 2000 according to msdn, how about using SHGetFolderPath? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181(v=vs.85).aspx 
If you need to force the coding type, at winapi you usually have endings with W for wchar_t, A for char. Such as SHGetFolderPathA. This one should support from Win 2000 up to this day, even tho it's set for deprecation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `T` type means that `SHGetSpecialFolderPath` is a pair of functions:

- `SHGetSpecialFolderPathA` for Windows ANSI encoded `char` based text, and
- `SHGetSpecialFolderPathW` for UTF-16 encoded `wchar_t` based text, Windows' “Unicode”.

The ANSI variant is just a wrapper for the Unicode variant, and it **can not** logically produce a correct path in all cases.

But this is what you need to use for `char` based data.

---

An alternative is to use the wide variant of the function, and use whatever machinery that you're comfortable with to convert the wide text result to a byte-oriented `char` based encoding of your choice, e.g. UTF-8.

Note that UTF-8 strings can't be used directly to open files etc. via the Windows API, so this approach involves even more conversion just to use the string.

---

However, I recommend switching over to wide text, in Windows.

For this, define the macro symbol `UNICODE` before including `<windows.h>`.

That's also the default in a Visual Studio project.

Comment: What impact does switching over to wide text have on my project? It is currently configured as `Use Multi-Byte Character Set`.

Comment: @Z0q: Literals and strings in calls of API functions need to be changed to wide. Mostly that's just prefixing an `L`. E.g., where with ANSI you had `"hello"`, with Unicode you have `L"Hello"`.

Comment: If I call `fopen()` for example, how would I send a wide text as parameter?

Comment: @Z0q: You can't use standard `fopen` to open an arbitrary file in Windows, because the path needs to be ANSI-encoded, and so it can't handle all the possible path characters. You can use Windows-specific `_wfopen` to do it. Or you can go one level higher and use the Boost filesystem sublibrary, which (possibly slightly modified) will be part of C++17.

Comment: Would it be a problem for my application if I use the ANSI encoded char based text? It would save me a lot of time rewriting large parts of my code

Comment: It will be unable to handle some paths, that's all. For example, if you're writing this program in the US, and someone in some Asian or Arabic or Eastern European country uses it, they may run into problems.

Comment: Thanks. I'll use that one for now, and migrate in a future update :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `SHGetSpecialFolderPathA()` to have the function deal with ANSI characters explicitly.

Then, just convert the array of `char` to `std::string` as usual.

```
/* to have MinGW declare SHGetSpecialFolderPathA() */
#if !defined(_WIN32_IE) || _WIN32_IE < 0x0400
#undef _WIN32_IE
#define _WIN32_IE 0x0400
#endif

#include <shlobj.h>
#include <string>

std::string getPath(int csidl) {
    char out[MAX_PATH];
    if (SHGetSpecialFolderPathA(NULL, out, csidl, 0)) {
        return out;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd374131%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```
#ifdef UNICODE
    typedef wchar_t TCHAR;
#else
    typedef unsigned char TCHAR;
#endif
```

Basically you can can convert this array to `std::wstring`. Converting to `std::string` is straightforward with `std::wstring_convert`.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert

Answer (score 0):

Typedef String as either std::string or std::wstring depending on your compilation configuration. The following code might be useful:

```
#ifndef UNICODE  
  typedef std::string String; 
#else
  typedef std::wstring String; 
#endif
```